# Stanford CoreNLP API fails to parse some sentences

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have been trying to use the Stanford CoreNLP API included in the 2015-12-09 release. I start the server using:

```
java -mx5g -cp "./*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipelinStanfordCoreNLPServer
```

The server works in general, but fails for some setnences including the following:

```
"Aside from her specifically regional accent, she reveals by the use of the triad, ``irritable, tense, depressed, a certain pedantic itemization that indicates she has some familiarity with literary or scientific language ( i.e., she must have had at least a high­school education ) , and she is telling a story she has mentally rehearsed some time before."
```

I end up with a result that starts with :

```
{"sentences":[{"index":0,"parse":"SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE","basic-dependencies":
```

I would greatly appriciate some help in setting this up - am I not including some annotators in the nlp pipeline.

This same sentence works at http://corenlp.run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a dependency parse (like that in [corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run)), you should look at the `basic-dependencies` field rather than the `parse` field. If you want a constituency parse, you should include the `parse` annotator in the list of annotators you are sending to the server. By default, the server does not include the parser annotator, as it's relatively slow.